# How to check current row start date with previous row end date for entire table across ID1 and ID2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following data in table [billStaging]:

```
Rowid     billStartDate     billEndDate     customerId     propertyId     dateStatus
1         2013-02-06        2013-03-01      87582000       0087582
2         2013-01-05        2013-02-05      87582000       0087582
3         2012-12-06        2013-01-04      87582000       0087582
4         2012-11-07        2012-12-05      87582000       0087582
```

I need to verify for each propertyid that the Rowid 1 [billEndDate] is not >= Rowid 2 [billStartDate]. If true, output 'OK' to in the last query for this record, else output 'Date Issue'.

Each propertyId will have differing numbers of rows, and 1 or more different customerId's.  Each customerId could be associated with more than one propertyId and the Rowid 1 [billEndDate] is not >= Rowid 2 [billStartDate] applies in that way as well.

This is what I have so far:

```
-- 1ST TEMP TABLE SORTS THE TABLE BY ENDDT DESC, AND ASSIGNS A ROW NUMBER, RESETTING TO 1
-- FOR EACH CUSTOMERID

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customerID order by billEndDate desc) as 'Row'
          ,billStartDate
          ,billEndDate
          ,customerId
          ,propertyId
      INTO #tabl1
      FROM billStaging


    -- 2ND TEMP TABLE SELECTS FROM THE FIRST WHERE THE ROW NUMBER IS 2.  THIS WILL SELECT THE RECORD WITH THE ENDDT 
    -- BEFORE THE MOST RECENT RECORD

        select *
          into #tabl2
          from #tabl1
         where row=2


-- 3RD TEMP TABLE SELECTS UNIQUE CUSTOMERIDS AND THE LATEST STARTDT 

    select customerId,
           propertyId, MAX(billStartDate) as billStartDate 
     into #tabl3
     FROM billStaging


-- 4TH TABLE COMBINES THE OUTPUT FROM THE SECOND AND THE THIRD TABLE, SHOWING CUSTOMERID,
-- STARTDATE FROM THE MOST RECENT RECORD, AND ENDDT FROM THE RECORD PRIOR TO THAT.  IT ALSO
-- HAS A CASE SELECTION TO DISPLAY TRUE OR FALSE DEPENDING ON THE RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN THE TWO DATES
-- YOU CAN ALSO RESTRICT THE FINAL PULL OF RECORDS IN THE WHERE CLAUSE.

    select t3.customerid, t3.propertyId, t2.billStartDate, t2.billEndDate, CASE WHEN T2.billEndDate < T3.billStartDate THEN 'OK' ELSE 'Date Issue' END as 'Date Issue'
    from #tabl3 t3, #tabl2 t2
    where t3.propertyId=t2.propertyId
    and t3.customerId=t2.customerId
```

Sample output:

```
Row billStartDate   billEndDate     customerId      propertyId     dateStatus
5   2012-09-14      2012-11-14      140044944       14004494       OK
1   2013-01-11      2013-03-12      140044969       14004496       OK
2   2013-01-11      2013-03-07      140044969       14004496       Date Issue
3   2012-11-15      2013-01-10      140044969       14004496       OK
4   2012-11-20      2012-12-21      140044969       14004496       Date Issue
5   2012-09-24      2012-11-14      140044969       14004496       OK
6   NULL            NULL            140044969       14004496       Date Issue
1   2013-03-13      2013-05-09      140044973       14004497       OK
2   2013-01-11      2013-03-12      140044973       14004497       OK
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Jeff

Comment: if you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use lead and lag functions

Comment: Some sample expected output might be helpful to go along with your description, and maybe make sure the sample covers the various situations.